# Single Unique Attribute for a bunch of EF classes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, data-annotations

I have a bunch of classes generated by EF ( simplified ):

```
public class Country
{
    [UniqueCountry(ErrorMessage = "Record previously added")]
    public String COUNTRY { get; set; }
}

public class Region
{
    [UniqueRegion(ErrorMessage = "Record previously added")]
    public String REGION { get; set; }
}

public class City
{
    [UniqueCity(ErrorMessage = "Record previously added")]
    public String CITY { get; set; }
}
```

Then, I have 3 separate views to create or edit these entities.
I want to make sure that values entered by user are unique, and if it is not - give to a user an error message. This way I want to use DataAnnotation attributes

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class UniqueCountryAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        var model = value as string;
        using (var db = new myEntities())
        {
            return !db.Country.Any(p => p.COUNTRY.ToLower() == model.ToLower());
        }
    }
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class UniqueRegionAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        var model = value as string;
        using (var db = new myEntities())
        {
            return !db.Region.Any(p => p.REGION.ToLower() == model.ToLower());
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to avoid creating a unique attribute per each class and avoid creating monster-switch?

The only difference between them is a table name and a column name of the context.

Comment: if you use T4template for your entites then you can edit YourModal.tt file